# Два сервиса на одном сервере

Tags: c#, wcf, сервисы, configuration

Добрый день!

Спасибо что зашли. Я столкнулся с такой задачей.

Есть сервер, на нем установлены в IIS 4  WCF-сервиса:

```
Service1 : 1100 (основной)
Service2 : 1101
Service3 : 1102
Service4 : 1103
```

Первый сервис вызывает второй. В принципе тут не было бы ничего сложного, если бы не сертификаты. Это сделано для того, чтобы софт. могли юзать только авторизованные приложения.

Ошибка при вызове сервиса 2:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   ':1101'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was
>   aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Я проверил сертификаты - мы заходим на второй сервис с нужным сертификатом. У меня есть подозрения, что ошибка в веб-конфиге.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему? Я с сертификатами только начинаю работать.**

*Ниже находится мой веб-конфиг:*

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DSN" connectionString="........."/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://SERVER:1101/PinSetup.svc/SoapBufferedCert"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPinSetup"
        contract="PinSetupService.IPinSetup" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPinSetup" behaviorConfiguration="clientEndpointCredential"/>
      <endpoint address="https://SERVER:1102/Service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISmsGate"
        contract="SmsGateServiceReference.ISmsGate" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISmsGate" />
      <endpoint address="https://SERVER:1103/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_FZCoreModuleContract_2_1"
        contract="SrNotifyService.FZCoreModuleContract_2_1" name="BasicHttpBinding_FZCoreModuleContract_2_1" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CertCoreBehavior" name="PrepaidServiceNS.PrepaidService">
        <endpoint address="SoapBufferedCert" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityBinding" contract="PrepaidServiceNS.IPrepaid"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <!--  Сертификаты  -->
        <behavior name="CertCoreBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling
              maxConcurrentSessions="1000"
              maxConcurrentCalls="1000"
              maxConcurrentInstances="10000" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false" includeWindowsGroups="false"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />              
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="clientEndpointCredential">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="j-TestCertClient" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecurityBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPinSetup">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISmsGate">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_FZCoreModuleContract_2_1">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу дать три рекомендации на сей счет:

1. Всегда обновляться в  Service References ссылку на сервис после его апдейта на сервере
2. проверяйте доступ пользователя, под которым запущен Пул, к физической папке сервиса
3. проверьте **сертификаты** и **ендпоинты**

Мне это помогло.

Comment: P.S. с веб-конфигом все в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Надо обращаться к серверу по тому же имени, которое прописано в сертификате. Для всех остальных сертификат будет невалидным. Если сертификат выдан на `smth.comecompany.com`, то обращение через `localhost` или ip-адрес будет неверным.

Ещё надо убедиться, что сертификат привязан к порту. Если сертификат не совсем валидный (для разработки, когда ещё добавляется рутовый сертификат, который тоже сгенерирован), привязка к портам слетает при перезагрузке. Надо перепривязать заново.

Comment: совершенно верное замечание. Спасибо.

Comment: @LeonardBertone, верное - в смысле помогло, или в смысле, что ты уже об этом в курсе?)